# Mozilla Firefox hanging on Ubuntu 22.04 when type Ctrl+S by accident

Tags: firefox, mozilla

I have a problem Mozilla Firefox hanging on Ubuntu 22.04 when type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> by accident.

And I have to restart the browser to use it.

[image]

Comment: I've experienced this with Ctrl+O as well. The results are just as frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the "window dialog" without close `Firefox` you can try <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+W</kbd> or you can try the `xkill` command in a terminal which will give you a cursor to click any window

If you want to close the firefox process, you can do it this way:
first find its corresponding pid

```
ps -ef | grep firefox
```

you have to replace 12345 by the PID you found in the precedent step

copy the PID and kill it like that `sudo kill 12345`

if it still dont work you can force it this way `sudo kill -9 12345`

Comment: I want to close the "window dialog" without close Firefox.

Comment: @Alchimie And the `Cancel`-button (top left corner of the dialog window) does not work?

Comment: The '''cancel''' button doesn't work, not even the save button.

Comment: @Alchimie I updated my answer, maybe it will fix your problem

Comment: @Saxtheowl "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "W" Not worked but worked well with xkill . thank you friend.

Comment: You welcome :))

Comment: @Alchimie: The Cancel button does work, but it looks like it does not because there are many identical dialog boxes beneath it that take its place when it closes. See my answer to know more.

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed this issue on Ubuntu 23.04 shipped Firefox (snap) too. Seems like this bug is still not solved.

What's actually happening is, even though Ctrl+S is pressed only once, for some reason it triggers the "Save Webpage" functionality multiple times. Thus, multiple dialog boxes are opened, one on top of the other. That's why the window shadow looks like a back halo around the window.

**To close all of them without closing Firefox, simply click the dialog box to put focus on it, and press and hold the Esc key until all dialog boxes are destroyed.**

Or alternatively, you could continuously click the Cancel button in the top-left corner of the dialog box until all of them are destroyed. Note: If you only click the Cancel button once, it does close the top-most visible dialog box, but it looks like nothing happened because there are so many dialog boxes open below it in the same position and size.

Comment: its working , but `xkill` method more efficient

Comment: @Alchimie: True, but won't work on Wayland. Maybe an equivalent tool can be created for Wayland too, but would be difficult because Wayland is much more strict than X.org.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem is probably because of the conflict between Firefox and Wayland on Ubuntu 22.04.

You can simply append `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` to the file `/etc/environment` to enable Wayland support for Firefox. [Method Reference](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/09/enable-wayland-firefox-chrome/). Sadly I didn't find an easier way to enable this flag in firefox.

And after that, you can also get a much more smooth experience.

Comment: Thank you! This solution appears to have worked great for me and is much better than closing 100 windows every time I press save...